# NDB datastore, how to find entity size?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I use a python appengine backend for my mobile app which periodically sends user preferences to the backend using cloud endpoints.

My python backend processes these preferences and updates the user's entity. I am afraid that the user entity could blow up to be > 1MB and I would like to periodically check the datastore entity sizes and transfer the preferences to cloud storage.

I cannot find any public method to check for an NDB datastore's entities size, does anybody else know how?

Answer (score 0):

I quick and dirty way would be to just go to your cloud dev console:

https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~YOUR-APP-NAME/datastore/indexes

That would give you a good idea.